# Chart js pie chart not showing dynamic data using JSON

Tags: javascript, json, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, chart.js

I am trying to make a pie chart in my project but I am having problem in getting the data from the database. I am currently using codeigniter and bootstrap template with built in chart.js on it.

here is my chart table:
[charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FZF1.png)

Controller:

```
public function loadViewExamResult($exam_no){

    $this->load->model('exam_model');
    $this->insertChartData($exam_no);

    $data = $this->exam_model->loadChartData($exam_no);
    echo json_encode($data);

    $this->load->view('exam_report_chart', $data);
}


public function insertChartData($exam_no){
    $this->load->model('exam_model');

    $pass = $this->exam_model->passedScore($exam_no);
    echo($pass);
    $fail = $this->exam_model->failedScore($exam_no);

    echo($fail);
    $this->exam_model->insertPieData($exam_no,$pass,$fail);

}
```

Model:

```
public function loadChartData($exam_no){
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT passed, failed FROM chart where exam_no = '$exam_no';");

        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            return $query->result();
        }

        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

View (snippet):

```
  <?php
    if($exams != NULL){
    foreach($exams as $row){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row->course_code.' '.$row->section.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row->exam_desc.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row->exam_date.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row->duration.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row->total_items.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row->total_score.'</td>';
    echo '<td> <div class="btn-group"> <a class="btn btn-success" onclick = "editExam('.$row->exam_no.')"><i class="icon_pencil-edit"></i></a> <a class="btn btn-danger" onclick = "deleteExam('.$row->exam_no.')"><i class="icon_close_alt2"></i></a> <a class="btn btn-primary"  onclick="addExamKey('.$row->exam_no.')"><i class="icon_cloud-download"></i></a> <a class="btn btn-default" role="button" onclick = "viewExamResult('.$row->exam_no.')"> View Result </a> </div> </td>';
    echo    '</tr>';
            }                       
        }
?>
     <script language="javascript">
        function viewExamResult($exam_no){
            $("#main-content").load("loadViewExamResult/" +$exam_no +"/").hide(500).fadeIn();
        }

    </script>
```

And here is the chart.js file that is already in the bootstrap template and you just have to customize it according to your data. I have already edited it and I think I'm having a problem in the JSON part that is why the pie graph isn't showing. Can someone help me with this? I actually have little knowledge about JSON and javascript. please help me.

chart.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var numpassed =[];
var numfailed =[];

$.post("<?php echo base_url(). ;?>",
    function(data){

        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        $.each(obj,function(i,item){
            numpassed.push(item.passed);
            numfailed.push(item.failed);
        });

        var doughnutData = [
            {
                value: numpassed,
                color:"#F7464A"
            },
            {
                value : numfailed,
                color : "#46BFBD"
            },

        ];
    });

new Chart(document.getElementById("doughnut").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are trying to create chart without waiting your post call return data. Move your chart creation code into $.post callback like this:

```
$.post("<?php echo base_url(). ;?>",
function(data){

    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    $.each(obj,function(i,item){
        numpassed.push(item.passed);
        numfailed.push(item.failed);
    });

    var doughnutData = [
        {
            value: numpassed,
            color:"#F7464A"
        },
        {
            value : numfailed,
            color : "#46BFBD"
        },

    ];

    new Chart(document.getElementById("doughnut").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData);
});
```

Comment: But how can I call the controller function that loads the data? I'm actually having an error with that.

Comment: What is the error you are getting right now? If base_url() is a valid endpoint you should get a proper array there that you will use to create your Chart.

Comment: page not found.  Maybe because the controller that loads the data was not called?